# Return value from Kotlin coroutines inside a non-suspended function

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that I override, and I cannot mark it with `suspend`.

```
override fun doSmth(): String
```

Inside it, I need to introduce a non-blocking delay, so I used `kotlinx.coroutines.time.delay` inside a coroutine.

```
override fun doSmth(): String {
    runBlocking {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(1000L)
            val result: String = doAnotherThing()
            // How to return this result from doSmth?
        }
    }
}
```

How to return this result value to the caller of `doSmth()`?

Comment: You can’t do this. `runBlocking` blocks. But to get the result, you would use `async` instead of `launch` and call `await` on the returned Deferred.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to introduce a non-blocking delay

How do you expect this to work from your caller's perspective?

Because of your function's signature, you have to block the calling thread until the String is ready. No matter how complex (or async) you make the internals of the function, the constraint stays: the caller has to synchronously wait.

Using `runBlocking` here does exactly that: make the caller thread actually *block* until whatever is inside is done. This is why there is no point in using `launch` if you wrap the whole contents of `runBlocking`. Instead, you can simply call `doAnotherThing()` directly:

```kotlin
override fun doSmth(): String {
    return runBlocking {
        delay(1000L)
        doAnotherThing() // last expression is the return value
    }
}
```

That being said, if you're blocking the calling thread anyway, why not just use the *blocking* `Thread.sleep()` instead?

```kotlin
override fun doSmth(): String {
    Thread.sleep(1000L)
    return doAnotherThing()
}
```